# error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0' unaligned pointer,aboted, press any key to continue

Tags: boot

after long time ,i log in to Ubuntu shows this message after selecting booting option for Ubuntu please help me .

Answer (score 0):

This is a GRUB error. GRUB is probably quite a difficult environment for troubleshooting. Instead, you might try to boot from a Ubuntu Live USB, and then re-install GRUB.

You will need some reliable instructions for this.  If you have the correct instructions, hopefully it will fix the problem.  But even if it does not fix the problem, hopefully the instructions will show an error message, or you will be able to see that something specific is missing, etc.

NOTE: "When using a LiveCD, due to GRUB 2 changes between Ubuntu releases, it is recommended that the user boots a LiveCD of the same release (11.10, 12.04, etc) as the release to be repaired."  There are instructions [on the Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System), under "via the LiveCD terminal".  I have not tried following them recently, so I can only hope they are correct and up-to-date.

Alternatively, the Ubuntu wiki mentions an *unofficial* tool called Boot-Repair.  I have not tested this tool either.  Personally I am quite wary in case an automatic tool does something unexpected and breaks something else.  It is probably easier to use when it works, but more complicated to understand if it hits a problem or not.

If using Boot-Repair, please make sure that "When repair is finished, note the URL (paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX) that appeared on a paper, then reboot and check if you recovered access to your OSs."  Then, "If the repair did not succeed, indicate the URL to people who help you by email or forum."

> Boot-Repair is a GUI application which can fix a variety of GRUB 2 problems. It can be used either from a LiveCD, its own CD, or during a normal Ubuntu session. In addition to providing a simple user interface, Boot-Repair also includes the ability to run a script to gather details of the system which can be used for troubleshooting help on various forums and IRC channels.
>
> Please refer to the [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) community documentation for instructions on how to install and run this application.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by
removing my RAM 
and clean it 
then I re insert it 
then these problem is fixed in my system